# ant build failed to create task or type svn error

Tags: xml, svn, ant

I have executed the following commands

```
export ANT_HOME=/xenv/ant/X/1.7.1
export SVN_HOME=/xenv/svn-c/X/1.6.6l_64
export PATH=$PATH:$HOME/bin:$JAVA_HOME/bin:$SVN_HOME/bin:$ANT_HOME/bin:$ORACLE_HOME/bin
```

I have a apphermes.xml file and when I execute this command

```
ant -f apphermes.xml tar.zip
```

I am getting the following error at apphermes.xml :66:

```
 Problem: failed to create task or type svn
 Cause: The name is undefined.
 Action: Check the spelling.
 Action: Check that any custom tasks/types have been declared.
 Action: Check that any <presetdef>/<macrodef> declarations have taken place
```

In apphermes.xml at 66 line I have the following code :

```
 <!-- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
 63               target: svn.checkout
 64          - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -->
 65     <target name="svn.checkout" depends="prepare,svn.login">
 66         <svn username="${svn.username}" password="${svn.password}">
 67             <checkout url="${svn.app.path}" revision="${svn.revision}" destPath="${build.dir}/svn/${svn.app.dirname}" />
 68             <checkout url="${svn.commons}" revision="${svn.revision}" destPath="${build.dir}/svn/commons" />
 69             <checkout url="${svn.release}" destPath="${build.dir}/svn/release" />
 70             <info target="${svn.revision.check.root}" />
 71         </svn>
```

EDIT :

```
 <typedef resource="org/tigris/subversion/svnant/svnantlib.xml" classpathref="svnant.classpath" />

<taskdef resource="net/sf/antcontrib/antlib.xml">
  <classpath>
    <pathelement location="${env.ANT_CONTRIB}/ant-contrib-1.0b3.jar"/>
  </classpath>
</taskdef>
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you have the SVN Ant tasks defined?  In our build we have this line at the top:

```
<typedef resource="org/tigris/subversion/svnant/svnantlib.xml" classpath="svnant.jar"/>
```

and then we can reference the  task just fine.

Comment: Is the svnant.jar in your $ANT_HOME/lib folder?

Comment: @mikemil can you check this question please http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40628790/typedef-java-util-zip-zipexception-error-in-opening-zip-file?noredirect=1#comment68490560_40628790

Comment: Sorry but I about 3 years removed from that environment at this point.  I probably wouldn't be much help. :-(