# typedef java.util.zip.ZipException: error in opening zip file

Tags: java, svn, ant

I am getting the below error

```
  [typedef]     at java.util.zip.ZipFile.open(Native Method)
  [typedef]     at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:114)
  [typedef]     at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:131)
  [typedef]     at org.apache.tools.ant.AntClassLoader.getResourceURL(AntClassLoader.java:1028)
  [typedef]     at org.apache.tools.ant.AntClassLoader$ResourceEnumeration.findNextResource(AntClassLoader.java:147)
  [typedef]     at org.apache.tools.ant.AntClassLoader$ResourceEnumeration.nextElement(AntClassLoader.java:130)
  [typedef]     at org.apache.tools.ant.util.CollectionUtils$CompoundEnumeration.nextElement(CollectionUtils.java:198)
  [typedef]     at sun.misc.CompoundEnumeration.nextElement(CompoundEnumeration.java:43)
  [typedef]     at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Definer.execute(Definer.java:260)
  [typedef]     at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:288)
  [typedef]     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
  [typedef]     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
  [typedef]     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
  [typedef]     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
  [typedef]     at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
  [typedef]     at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
  [typedef]     at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.execute(Target.java:357)
  [typedef]     at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.performTasks(Target.java:385)
  [typedef]     at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeSortedTargets(Project.java:1337)
  [typedef]     at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTarget(Project.java:1306)
  [typedef]     at org.apache.tools.ant.helper.DefaultExecutor.executeTargets(DefaultExecutor.java:41)
  [typedef]     at org.eclipse.ant.internal.ui.antsupport.EclipseDefaultExecutor.executeTargets(EclipseDefaultExecutor.java:32)
  [typedef]     at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTargets(Project.java:1189)
  [typedef]     at org.eclipse.ant.internal.ui.antsupport.InternalAntRunner.run(InternalAntRunner.java:423)
```

this the ant file

```
<project name="Hello World Project" default="testchk">

  <property file="build.properties"/>

<target name="testchk">
      <echo>Hello</echo>


 <path id="path.svnant">
                <pathelement location="${ant-jar-dir}\SVN1.8.Client\svnant.jar" />
                <pathelement location="${ant-jar-dir}\SVN1.8.Client\svnClientAdapter.jar" />
                <pathelement location="${ant-jar-dir}\SVN1.8.Client\svnkit-javahl-1.8.0.jar" />
                <pathelement location="${ant-jar-dir}\SVN1.8.Client\svnkit-1.8.0.jar" />
                <pathelement location="${ant-jar-dir}\SVN1.8.Client\sqljet-1.1.8.jar" />
                <pathelement location="${ant-jar-dir}\SVN1.8.Client\antlr-runtime-3.4.jar" />
                <pathelement location="${ant-jar-dir}\SVN1.8.Client\sequence-library-1.0.2.jar" />
 </path>    


    <typedef resource="org/tigris/subversion/svnant/svnantlib.xml" classpathref="path.svnant" />



    <echo>Greetings ${ant-jar-dir}</echo>

</target>

</project>
```

this is the build file

```
ant-jar-dir=D:/ant
```

this is the output

```
 [echo] Greetings D:/ant
```

this is the full logcat

```
testchk:
     [echo] Hello World - Welcome to Apache Ant! https://lbsm8-svn.path.local/svn/DB_Scripts/SCRIPTS/WALIDTEST
  [typedef] java.util.zip.ZipException: error in opening zip file
  [typedef]     at java.util.zip.ZipFile.open(Native Method)
  [typedef]     at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:114)
  [typedef]     at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:131)
  [typedef]     at org.apache.tools.ant.AntClassLoader.getResourceURL(AntClassLoader.java:1028)
  [typedef]     at org.apache.tools.ant.AntClassLoader$ResourceEnumeration.findNextResource(AntClassLoader.java:147)
  [typedef]     at org.apache.tools.ant.AntClassLoader$ResourceEnumeration.nextElement(AntClassLoader.java:130)
  [typedef]     at org.apache.tools.ant.util.CollectionUtils$CompoundEnumeration.nextElement(CollectionUtils.java:198)
  [typedef]     at sun.misc.CompoundEnumeration.nextElement(CompoundEnumeration.java:43)
  [typedef]     at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Definer.execute(Definer.java:260)
  [typedef]     at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:288)
  [typedef]     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
  [typedef]     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
  [typedef]     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
  [typedef]     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
  [typedef]     at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
  [typedef]     at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
  [typedef]     at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.execute(Target.java:357)
  [typedef]     at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.performTasks(Target.java:385)
  [typedef]     at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeSortedTargets(Project.java:1337)
  [typedef]     at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTarget(Project.java:1306)
  [typedef]     at org.apache.tools.ant.helper.DefaultExecutor.executeTargets(DefaultExecutor.java:41)
  [typedef]     at org.eclipse.ant.internal.ui.antsupport.EclipseDefaultExecutor.executeTargets(EclipseDefaultExecutor.java:32)
  [typedef]     at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTargets(Project.java:1189)
  [typedef]     at org.eclipse.ant.internal.ui.antsupport.InternalAntRunner.run(InternalAntRunner.java:423)
  [typedef]     at org.eclipse.ant.internal.ui.antsupport.InternalAntRunner.main(InternalAntRunner.java:137)
  [typedef] java.util.zip.ZipException: error in opening zip file
  [typedef]     at java.util.zip.ZipFile.open(Native Method)
  [typedef]     at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:114)
  [typedef]     at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:131)
  [typedef]     at org.apache.tools.ant.AntClassLoader.getResourceURL(AntClassLoader.java:1028)
  [typedef]     at org.apache.tools.ant.AntClassLoader$ResourceEnumeration.findNextResource(AntClassLoader.java:147)
  [typedef]     at org.apache.tools.ant.AntClassLoader$ResourceEnumeration.nextElement(AntClassLoader.java:130)
  [typedef]     at org.apache.tools.ant.util.CollectionUtils$CompoundEnumeration.nextElement(CollectionUtils.java:198)
  [typedef]     at sun.misc.CompoundEnumeration.nextElement(CompoundEnumeration.java:43)
  [typedef]     at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Definer.execute(Definer.java:260)
  [typedef]     at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:288)
  [typedef]     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
  [typedef]     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
  [typedef]     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
  [typedef]     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
  [typedef]     at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
  [typedef]     at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
  [typedef]     at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.execute(Target.java:357)
  [typedef]     at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.performTasks(Target.java:385)
  [typedef]     at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeSortedTargets(Project.java:1337)
  [typedef]     at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTarget(Project.java:1306)
  [typedef]     at org.apache.tools.ant.helper.DefaultExecutor.executeTargets(DefaultExecutor.java:41)
  [typedef]     at org.eclipse.ant.internal.ui.antsupport.EclipseDefaultExecutor.executeTargets(EclipseDefaultExecutor.java:32)
  [typedef]     at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTargets(Project.java:1189)
  [typedef]     at org.eclipse.ant.internal.ui.antsupport.InternalAntRunner.run(InternalAntRunner.java:423)
  [typedef]     at org.eclipse.ant.internal.ui.antsupport.InternalAntRunner.main(InternalAntRunner.java:137)
     [echo] Greetings D:/Copyof
BUILD SUCCESSFUL
```

Comment: What exception did you get? You only show the stack trace.

Comment: @marstran I add the full log cat